# How can I partition data based on DATE Ranges in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I get the desired Output.

**Logic**: IDs / Records should be partitioned based on Date range, but condition is record should fall within starting (First Start Date) and Ending (Latest End Date) Date Range.

| ID | Start_Date | End_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-03-31 |
| 1 | 2022-02-15 | 2022-04-15 |
| 1 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-03-31 |
| 1 | 2022-11-02 | 2022-11-06 |
| 1 | 2022-11-20 | 2022-11-23 |

OUTPUT

| ID | Start_Date | End_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-04-15 |
| 1 | 2022-11-02 | 2022-11-06 |
| 1 | 2022-11-20 | 2022-11-23 |

Comment: "*Records should be partitioned based on Date range*" - There's no date range specified in the post. Why record 2 and 3 get merged?

Comment: You need to explain the logic here. As posted this just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Felt like you were heading for a typical Gaps-and-Islands solution, but your sample data and desired results doesn't make sense.

Comment: OK with the update, you are looking for a Gaps and Islands

Comment: Now you have changed the sample data but it still doesn't make any sense. Why is the first row by itself but the second and third rows are combined? All three of those rows overlap each other.

Comment: @SeanLange I have updated now. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Yes that makes sense now. As @JohnCappelletti said this is a typical gaps and islands type of query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach to a date-ranged `Gaps-and-Islands`

****Example****

```
Select id
      ,Start_Date=min(D)
      ,End_Date  =max(D)
 From ( 
        Select ID
              ,D 
              ,Grp = dense_rank() over (partition by id order by D)
                   - datediff(day,0,D)
         From  YourTable A
         Join  ( Select Top 5000 N=-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) From master..spt_values n1, master..spt_values n2 ) B
           on  N<=datediff(day,[Start_date],[End_Date])
         Cross Apply ( values ( convert(date,dateadd(DAY,N,[start_date]))  )  ) C(D)
      ) A
 Group By ID,Grp
 Order By ID,min(D)
```

**Results**

```
id  Start_Date  End_Date
1   2022-01-01  2022-04-15
1   2022-11-02  2022-11-06
1   2022-11-20  2022-11-23
```

Comment: OMG! I couldn't have done it with the method I was attempting earlier. This is simply amazing. Thank you very much. I'm still testing a few of my cases with NULL scenarios and so on. Once completed, I would accept the response.